# Why is TinyMCE ignoring class styles that it's applied?

Tags: tinymce, css-float

I'm using the following config:

```
formats : {alignleft : {selector : 'img', classes : 'float-left'},
    alignright : {selector : 'img', classes : 'float-right'},
},
```

to make tiny use my custom classes for image alignment (which just set a css float of left or right) rather than applying them inline in styles.

Now, this works when I save the content and preview it, but in the tiny editor the image just stays where it is and won't float.

Inspecting the image code in Safari web inspector shows the class being correctly applied to the img element, it just doesn't.. float!

The page with the editor has access to the main stylesheet with the float-left and float-right classes too.

I'm new to tiny so perhaps I'm missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to see the class changes within the editor itself, you need to set a stylesheet during initialization.

```
tinyMCE.init({
    content_css : "/editor-style.css"    // http://domain.com/editor-style.css
});
```

That should pull in the stylesheet for your editor. Once the stylesheet is being pulled in you will have to add your styles to the stylesheet in order to see them display appropriately.

Comment: Thanks, fixed it! But are you able to explain why this is necessary? Why tiny can't use classes from the main stylesheet? Is it to do with tiny being inside an iframe or something?

Comment: You nailed it. The need for the stylesheet is because the TinyMCE editor is an iframe.

Comment: Asked, answered, understood.